# Netsuite Show Purchase Order in Email Template

Tags: email, tags, netsuite

I am trying to show the customer's purchase order number in the order-fulfilled email template. It's my own template design with the standard tags that netsuite provides.

I sent them a ticket asking if they have a tag like that, and apparently they do not. They said that feature in unavailable.

Is there a way that I can put a code into the email template that when the customer reads their email, they can view their purchase order number?

that's our customer's #1 question in regards to all the calls that we get is what their purchase order is. This can definitely help us out. I'm new to netsuite so I still do not know how to code around it or create a new tag.

Comment: In what field is the PO number stored? Is it in the standard field? Usually it is stored in "PO#", which can be called via <NLTRANID> tag in Email template

Comment: yes normally, the checkout process for everything except for our TOS is standard. Will try this code out. thanks!

Comment: @eliseobeltran for some reason it did not work. I wrote the PO# field as "test-order" and that should have appeared. 

we have fields before the submit button and it covers PO#, special instructions, and another dropbox. All of which are standard.

Comment: @eliseobeltran I just saw a list of tags I can use on the email template and <NLTRANID> is not on that list. Do I need to enable it somehow?

Comment: I think email template tags are readily available. When you go to this page https://system.netsuite.com/app/crm/common/merge/emailtemplate.nl you can select the dynamic field available by selecting 'Text Editor'. Set Field='Transaction' and the Insert field dropdown should populate with the available fields that can be use in the template

Comment: @eliseobeltran We're using the webstore email template. But I did see how I can get the tag from that page. Funny thing is, I saved the new template and now I don't know where to find it so I can replace my current order-fulfilled with the new one I just coded.

Comment: Show all the created webstore email template in this page so you can locate the old email template https://system.netsuite.com/app/site/setup/siteemailtemplates.nl

Comment: done that already, if I was to create one here; the NLTRANID will not be allowed. there's no place for me to set the field either, even when I select 'text editor'

Comment: The only workaround I can suggest is to create a custom field in that transaction and make it always copy the purchase order number. You can then call the value dynamically using the email template tags. Example if your custom field internal id is 'custbody_po_number' you can get the value using <NLCUSTOMBODY_PO_NUMBER> in the email template.

Comment: ah nice, I noticed when I viewed the page source, the tag id for the PO# input was "otherrefnum_fs" would I be able to use that?

Comment: ok, we'll give it a go with another test

Comment: @eliseobeltran yeah, that didnt work. This is where I'm referencing from: https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?topic=DOC_SetupWebSite_TagsAvailableforWebStoreEmailTemplates.html

Our order-fulfillment template is a webstore template, I can't put a regular email template there in place of it.

Answer (score 0):

Should work - This is the Live version we use.  Like they said, NLTRANID...but that is our PO reference for them which is our internal number...your client likely wants their clients' Reference PO numbers for b2b transaction transparency.

```
To:
<NLBILLADDRESS>


We are sending you the Purchase Order No <NLTRANID> as PDF attachment
```

Try this one too:  `<NLOTHERREFNUM>`

Comment: I did try that code too, keep in mind I'm still new to netsuite. But our order-fulfilled template is a webstore email template. I'm not sure if <NLOTHERREFNUM> will work because it does not appear as a tag that can be used on a webstore email template. On a regular email template sure, but our webstore one we're hitting blanks when we get the order-fulfilled email.